# Zend Framework 2 Email and Phone Validation

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

Am litle confused with email validations. In my model i define rules for form fields. My problem is that I do not know where to put  `Zend\Validator\EmailAddress()` rule. In standard InputFilter i have standard filters and validators like : `require`, `min`, `max`, `encode` ect. And does  ZF2 supports validation for phone numbers ?

I read this but i dont know how to mix EmailAddress rules in my model array `getInputFilter()`. Do i need define email validations in controller or i can do that in model ?

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html

My Model use Zend\InputFilter\ÍnputFilter and  i set rule like this :

```
      /**
         * Company Rules
         *
         * @filters
         *      StripTags | StringTrim
         * @validators
         *      StringLenght | UTF-8 encoding | min | max
         */

        $filter->add(array(
                'name' => 'company',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                        array(
                                'name' => 'StringLenght',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                        'min' => 2,
                                        'max' => 100,
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ));

        /**
         * Fax Rules
         *
         * @filters
         *      StripTags | StringTrim | Int
         * @validators
         *      StringLenght | UTF-8 encoding | min | max
         */

        $filter->add(array(
                'name' => 'fax',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                        array(
                                'name' => 'StringLenght',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                        'min' => 2,
                                        'max' => 100,
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can mix different validators writing styles in the following way:

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'name'    => 'StringLength',
        'options' => ...
    ),
    new \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress()
),
```

You can also specify EmailAddress validator using an array-like format:

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'name'    => 'StringLength',
        'options' => array(
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 100,
             ),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
    ),
),
```

Regarding validation of phone numbers, ZF2 doesn't provide validators ready for use (probably because there are so many differences between international phone numbers format), but using Zend\Validator\Regex you could implement one with not too much work.

Comment: Okay thanks for replay i will try this when i back from work.

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple and best suited way of email validation at-least for me

```
'validators' => array(

               array(

                    'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                    'options' =>array(
                        'domain'   => 'true',
                        'hostname' => 'true',
                        'mx'       => 'true',
                        'deep'     => 'true',
                        'message'  => 'Invalid email address',
                    ),
),
```